# Solving a separable ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would I take this further and solve the following:

I'm stuck on how to go from:

$(v^2-c_s^2)\frac{1}{v}\frac{dv}{dr} = 2\frac{c_s^2}{r^2}(r-r_c) $

to:

$(\frac{v}{c_S^2})^2-ln(\frac{v}{c_s^2})^2= 4 ln(\frac{r}{r_c})+4\frac{r_c}{r}+C$

I've tried integrating it as you would a regular ODE but get stuck on the answer of:

$\frac{v^2}{2}-c_s^2ln(v) = 2c_s^2[ln(r)+\frac{r_c}{r}]+C$

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I made some errors to the previous question and felt I should add extra detail. This problem is taking the previously derived expression and solving it as a **separable ODE**

Answer (score 1):

Integrate both sides with respect to $r$ to get
$$
\int\frac{v(r)^{2}-c_{s}^{2}}{v(r)}\frac{dv}{dr}(r)dr=2c_{s}^{2}\int\frac{r-r_{c}}{r^{2}}dr.
$$
Perform the substitution $u\equiv v(r)$ to get
$$
\int\frac{u^{2}-c_{s}^{2}}{u}du=2c_{s}^{2}\int\frac{r-r_{c}}{r^{2}}dr.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left.\frac{u^{2}}{2}-c_{s}^{2}\log u\right|_{v(a)}^{v(b)}=\left.2c_{s}^{2}\left(\frac{r_{c}}{r}+\log r\right)\right|_{a}^{b}.
$$
Now, multiply both sides by $2/c_{s}^{2}$ to get
$$
\left.\frac{u^{2}}{c_{s}^{2}}-2\log u\right|_{v(a)}^{v(b)}=4\left.\left(\frac{r_{c}}{r}+\log r\right)\right|_{a}^{b}.
$$
Since $c_{s}$ and $r_{c}$ are constants, this is equivalent to
$$
\left.\frac{u^{2}}{c_{s}^{2}}-2\log u-2\log c_{s}^{2}\right|_{v(a)}^{v(b)}=4\left.\left(\frac{r_{c}}{r}+\log r-\log r_{c}\right)\right|_{a}^{b}.
$$
Simplifying,
$$
\left.\frac{u^{2}}{c_{s}^{2}}-\log\left(\frac{u}{c_{s}^{2}}\right)^{2}\right|_{v(a)}^{v(b)}=4\left.\left(\frac{r_{c}}{r}+\log\left(\frac{r}{r_{c}}\right)\right)\right|_{a}^{b}.
$$

Comment: Since $c_{s}$ and $r_{c}$ are constants, this is equivalent to
$$
\left.\frac{u^{2}}{c_{s}^{2}}-2\log u-2\log c_{s}^{2}\right|_{v(a)}^{v(b)}=4\left.\left(\frac{r_{c}}{r}+\log r-\log r_{c}\right)\right|_{a}^{b}.
$$

Thank you for your solution. What would the limits on both integrals be here? additionally, wouldn't the 

$-2ln(u)-2ln(c_s^2)$ terms not cancel?

Comment: Yes, I cannot seem to get your solution?